# Decimal to Binary is not working

Tags: java, android, converters

I know for a fact I'm missing something extremely small but i can not seem to get my code to compile without errors. I am attempting to get the text field to take in a decimal number and `OnClick`, it will spit out the numbers binary equivalent.

It keeps telling me to initialize Binary but if i set it to 0, that makes Binary '0' instead of converting the decimal number.

Any help will would great! This is is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();   
    }

    final EditText editDecimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDecimal);
    final EditText editBinary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBinary);
    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int decimal =       Integer.valueOf(editDecimal.getText().toString());
            int binary;


            editBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(binary));
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: And what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the variable `binary`. Instead you just need to do this:

```
editBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(decimal));
```